# How to validate the array filed in Flask WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I use Flask as a back-end for handling request from React front-end. I get below request:

```
{
    "ids":[1,2,3,4,5],
    "other_field":"...",
    "csrf_token":"token"
}
```

I use `wtforms` to validate my inputs. For `ids` param, the front-end should send array with at least one value and not exceed 10 values, otherwise it should not validate the form.

I tried below code, without getting desire result.

```
class validate(FlaskForm):
    # other validations
    ids      = FieldList(IntegerField('ids'), min_entries=1, max_entries=10)
```

Comment: The form field you wrote expects a different format. (`('ids-0', 1), ('ids-1', 2), ...`) How do you submit your data that you get an array inside a form?

Comment: The data does not directly come from the input element but is based on some logic already defined. My only option is to accept an array as an input. Is there any easy way to do that with wtform? Otherwise, I should check manually.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to validate such formatting with wtforms. The array should be a JSON formatted or a comma separated string. Even then, validation would be complex. Since you use React in the front-end, I would advise you to do without wtforms in the back-end and to use [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I would transfer the data via json.

Comment: @Detlef thanks for your advice. lets see if others have other option or a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Detlef advice I switched to `webargs`. Below code Gives me the desire result.

```
from webargs import fields, validate
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args

@app.route("/",methods=['POST'])
@use_args({
    "ids": fields.List(fields.Int(),required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=1, max=10)])
}, location="json")
def index(args):
    return args["ids"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate the ids parameter in the incoming request using WTForms in Flask, you need to create a custom validator to check if the number of entries in the ids array falls within the desired range (at least one value and not exceeding 10 values). Here's how you can achieve that:

First, create a custom validator class for the ids parameter:

```
from wtforms import Form, FieldList, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

class ValidateIdsLength(object):
    def __init__(self, min_entries=1, max_entries=10, message=None):
        self.min_entries = min_entries
        self.max_entries = max_entries
        if not message:
            message = f'ids must have at least {min_entries} and at most {max_entries} entries.'
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if not self.min_entries <= len(field.data) <= self.max_entries:
            raise ValidationError(self.message)
```

Then, use the custom validator in your form:

```
class ValidateForm(Form):
    ids = FieldList(IntegerField('ids'), validators=[ValidateIdsLength()])
```

## Add other fields and validations as needed

Now, when you process the incoming request, you can use the ValidateForm to validate the data:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from wtforms import Form, FieldList, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

app = Flask(__name__)

class ValidateIdsLength(object):
    # Custom validator code as shown above...

class ValidateForm(Form):
    # Form definition with custom validator as shown above...

@app.route('/process_data', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    data = request.json
    form = ValidateForm(data=data)

    if form.validate():
        # Process the data here if the form is valid
        return jsonify({'message': 'Form is valid'})
    else:
        errors = form.errors
        return jsonify({'errors': errors})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, when the front-end sends a request with the ids parameter containing at least one value and not exceeding 10 values, the form will be considered valid. Otherwise, it will return the validation error with the specified message.

Note: Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed:

```
pip install Flask
pip install WTForms
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems not working. I print the content of `field` inside `ValidateIdsLength` it return `<ul id="ids"></ul>` instead of `list`. Do you have any idea how to solved?